# product compare block in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm new in Magento.

I try to insert content of default compare Magento block in special place in may theme.

I use following code in catalog.xml :

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar"   name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare  /sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

and following code in page.xml :

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
    <label>right defult Column</label>
</block>
```

but below code load all block with title i need content of compare block.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: which block it is loading?

Comment: @DeepKakkar  , Compare block and survey block and paypal Logo with block title